# Can a place name modify something else?

Tags: punctuation, possessives

I have looked up the proper way to punctuate place names (for example San Francisco, California) and am wondering if they can be used to modify something else.

Here is what I have so far:

> The “Spicy Ramen Festival” of San Jose, California, was held on April 7th at the Johnson Community Center.

But it sounds better to say verbally:

> **San Jose, California's** "Spicy Ramen Festival" was held on April 7th at the Johnson Community Center.

It this grammatical?

Comment: Your proposal sounds fine.   You can also say *The San Jose "Spicy Ramen Festival" was held on April 7th at the Johnson Community Center.*

Comment: "Are they the Yorkshire Dayles?"

Comment: I would use brackets for the widest geographical term: *"The San Jose (California) “Spicy Ramen Festival” was held at the Johnson Community Center on April 7th."* As there will be some context with the article, it is probable that *"(California)"* is not required. *"San Jose"* acts as an adjective to the proper noun phrase "Spicy Ramen Festival" and does not require a comma.

Comment: Many folks here could come up with dozens of examples in a New York minute.

Comment: If I were **talking**, I'd say what you said: San Jose, California's Spicy Ramen Festival. Bear in mind that if the place in a US state is well known, we lose the state: San Diego's Country Music Festival.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proposition does stand, although one noun (***festival***) with so many modifiers seem heavy to some. I found such instances similar to yours, some with the Genitive case:

> Morocco’s Fes Festival of World Sacred Music ([source](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/a-magical-tour-of-fes-mor_b_1627993))

and some without

> Glastonbury, England Music Festival, (see also [the Independent](https://www.independent.ie/woman/celeb-news/cancer-agony-of-pop-diva-kylie-25985629.html))

or

> New Orleans Louisiana Mardi Gras Festival Carnival Parade Crowd of People Cheering

(here the noun ***crowd*** is modified by an impressively long noun phrase, which makes me wonder just how long can a noun phrase modifying a noun can be!) ([source](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-new-orleans-louisiana-mardi-gras-festival-carnival-parade-crowd-of-19490157.html)).

However, when the modifying phrase is long, it is more common to use the preposition ***of***:

> The Mardi Gras festival of New Orleans ([readbastracts](http://www.readabstracts.com/Travel-recreation-and-leisure/Farewell-to-the-flesh-New-Orleans.html))

or ***in***:

> The Fes Festival of World Sacred Music in Morocco ([cordmagazine](https://cordmagazine.com/living/chill-out/the-fes-festival-of-world-sacred-music/)).

Comment: What the OP seems to principally interested in is how to apply ***'s*** to a name of a city that is accompanied by the name of the state/province/country. Is the answer to that question simply that it's not done?

Comment: @jw29 My first example is one such case. But it's true, I have not addressed that issue enough. Believe me, it is not easy to find such **'s** genitives with long names of festivals. If the name is shorter, it gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it sounds less awkward to say it this way: The Spicy Ramen Festival was held on April 7th at the Johnson Community Center in San Jose, California.

But, yes, a place name can be used to modify another noun. Your sentence is grammatical.

Example: San Francisco's famous Haight-Ashbury neighborhood ...

The only confusion might be if the name of the event is actually "Spicy Ramen Festival of San Jose, California" - is that the case? If so then the quotes should include "of San Jose, California." If you really need the quotes, although I don't see why.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is not the case. The name of the event is simply "Spicy Ramen Festival". The word order was selected to ephasize that the "Spicy Ramen Festival" is a festival of the city of San Jose. I am not sure that nuance will be preserved if I write "The Spicy Ramen Festival was held on April 7th at the Johnson Community Center in San Jose, California."

Comment: @Jeremy In that case, sure, why not, the Spicy Ramen Festival of San Jose (California, if needed)